# Intercepting hint event on delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, windows-messages, hint

I am trying to change hint text temporarily at a run-time inside of a component,
without changing the `Hint` property itself.

I've tried catching `CM_SHOWHINT`, but this event seems to only come to
form, but not the component itself.

Inserting CustomHint doesnt really work either, because it takes the text
from the `Hint` property.

my component is descendant from `TCustomPanel`

Here's what i'm trying to do:

```
procedure TImageBtn.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if (Message.Msg = CM_HINTSHOW) then
    PHintInfo(Message.LParam)^.HintStr := 'CustomHint';
end;
```

I've found this code somewhere in the internet, unfortunately it doesn't work tho.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`CM_HINTSHOW` is indeed just what you need. Here's a simple example:

```
type
  TButton = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton)
  protected
    procedure CMHintShow(var Message: TCMHintShow); message CM_HINTSHOW;
  end;

  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
  end;

....

procedure TButton.CMHintShow(var Message: TCMHintShow);
begin
  inherited;
  if Message.HintInfo.HintControl=Self then
    Message.HintInfo.HintStr := 'my custom hint';
end;
```

The code in the question is failing to call `inherited` which is probably why it fails. Or perhaps the the class declaration omits the `override` directive on `WndProc`. No matter, it's cleaner the way I have it in this answer.

Comment: You can also accomplish the same thing using the `TApplication.OnShowHint` event instead.

Comment: @Remy Pros and cons both ways. If you are writing a component then the message is best. If you want to apply application wide policy, then OnShowHint wins.

Answer (score 6):

You can use OnShowHint event

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnShowHint
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.AppEvnts.TCustomApplicationEvents.OnShowHint

It has HintInfo parameter: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Forms.THintInfo

That parameter lets you query the hint control, hint text and all that context - and override them it if needed.

If you want to filter which components to change hint for you may, for example, declare some kind of ITemporaryHint interface like

```
type 
  ITemporaryHint = interface 
  ['{1234xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}']
    function NeedCustomHint: Boolean;
    function HintText: string;
  end;
```

Then you can check later generically any of your components, whether they implement that interface

```
procedure TForm1.DoShowHint(var HintStr: string; var CanShow: Boolean;
  var HintInfo: THintInfo);
var
  ih: ITemporaryHint;
begin
  if Supports(HintInfo.HintControl, {GUID for ITemporaryHint}, ih) then
    if ih.NeedCustomHint then
      HintInfo.HintStr := ih.HintText;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.ShowHint := True;
  Application.OnShowHint := DoShowHint;
end;
```

Comment: Oh, @TLama, it seems inconsistent to do those replace together: boolean -> Boolean and String - string. However DoShowHint declaration is taken directly from Delphi DocWiki examples. I'd trust their choice of String.